# Open system browser on load cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have a Cordova application, which just opens a browser and load a mobile first website. I'm using it to initialize Push notifications. 
I'm using inAppbrowser. I would like to open the system browser (like Safari) instead of inApp browser.
Here is my code :

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {

        cordova.InAppBrowser.open('example.com','_system');
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

Even with the param '_system', Safari isn't launched.

Is there any way to open the default browser ?

Thanks

Comment: I feel that it would depend on the system config about which browser is used as default. Why don't you check the system config of OS X?

Comment: I'm accustomed to using `window.open(param, '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any particular settings in config.xml for this ? I just tried and the last log : "Finished load of : https://example.com", still in App, not in default browser.

Comment: Nothing special but `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.2" />` in **config.xml**. I wonder which version of inAppBrowser plugin you use now.

Comment: My version is `spec="^3.0.0"`, fresh installed from cordova plugin add command.

Answer (score 0):

With cordova-plugin-inappbrowser, i used "_blank" to open safari on iOS.

```
window.open(uri, "_blank");
```

Comment: Thanks, it's still the same. Default browser isn't opened on my side